# Difficult workflow writing Latex book full of Python code

Tags: python, latex, ipython, workflow, jupyter

I'm writing a book on coding in python using Latex. I plan on having a lot of text with python code interspersed throughout, along with its output. What's really giving me trouble is when I need to go back and edit my python code, it's a huge pain to get it back nicely into my latest document.

I've done a whole lot of research and can't seem to find a good solution.

This one includes full files as one, doesn't solve my issues
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289385/workflow-for-including-jupyter-aka-ipython-notebooks-as-pages-in-a-latex-docum

Same with this one.
http://blog.juliusschulz.de/blog/ultimate-ipython-notebook

**Found Solution 1 (awful)**

I can copy and paste python code into latex ok using the listings latex package.

Pros:

1. Easy to update only small section of code.

Cons:

1. For output need to run in python, copy, paste separately.
2. Initial writing SLOW, need to do this process hundreds of times per chapter.

**Found Solution 2 (bad)**

Use jupyter notebook with markdown, export to Latex, \include file into main Latex document.

Pros:

1. Streamlined
2. Has output contained within.

Cons:

- To make small changes, need to reimport whole document, any changes made to markdown text within Latex editor are not saved
- Renaming a single variable in python after jupyter notebook could take hours.
- Editing seems like a giant chore.

**Ideal solution**

- Write Text in Latex
- Write python in jupyter notebook, export to latex.
- Somehow include code snippets (small sections of the exported file) into *different parts* of the main latex book. **This is the part I can't figure out**
- When python changes are needed, changes in jupyter, then re-export as latex file with same name
- Latex book is automatically updated from includes.

The key here is that the exported python notebook is being split up and sent to different parts of the document. In order for that to work it needs to somehow be tagged or marked in the markdown or code of the notebook, so when I re-export it those same parts get sent to the same spots in the book.

Pros:

1. Python edits easy, easily propagated back to book.
2. Text written in latex, can use power of latex

Any help in coming up with a solution closer to my ideal solution would be much appreciated. It's killing me.

Probably doesn't matter, but I'm coding both latex and jupyter notebooks in VS Code. I'm open to changing tools if it means solving these problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a small script I wrote. It splits single `*.ipynb` file and converts it to multiple `*.tex` file.

Usage is:

1. copy following script and save as something like `main.py`
2. execute `python main.py init`. it will create `main.tex` and `style_ipython_custom.tplx`
3. in your jupyther notebook, add extra line `#latex:tag_a`, `#latex:tag_b`, .. to each cell which you want to extract. same tag will be extracted to same `*.tex` file.
4. save it as `*.ipynb` file. fortunately, current VSCode python plugin supports exporting to `*.ipynb`, or use jupytext to convert from `*.py` to `*.ipynb`.
5. run `python main.py path/to/your.ipynb` and it will create `tag_a.tex` and `tag_b.tex`
6. edit `main.tex` and add `\input{tag_a.tex}` or `\input{tag_b.tex}` where ever you want.
7. run `pdflatex main.tex` and it will produce `main.pdf`

The idea behind this script:

Converting from jupyter notebook to LaTex using default `nbconvert.LatexExporter` produces complete LaTex file which includes macro definitions. Using it to convert each cell will may create large LaTex file. To avoid the problem, the script first creates `main.tex` which has only macro definitions, and then converts each cell to LaTex file which has no macro defnition. This can be done using custom template file which is slightly modified from `style_ipython.tplx`

Tagging or marking the cell might be done using cell metadata, but I could not find how to set it in VSCode python plugin ([Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4142)), so instead it scans source of each cell with regex pattern `^#latex:(.*)`, and remove it before converting it to LaTex file.

Source:

```
import sys
import re
import os
from collections import defaultdict
import nbformat
from nbconvert import LatexExporter, exporters

OUTPUT_FILES_DIR = './images'
CUSTOM_TEMPLATE = 'style_ipython_custom.tplx'
MAIN_TEX = 'main.tex'


def create_main():
    # creates `main.tex` which only has macro definition
    latex_exporter = LatexExporter()
    book = nbformat.v4.new_notebook()
    book.cells.append(
        nbformat.v4.new_raw_cell(r'\input{__your_input__here.tex}'))
    (body, _) = latex_exporter.from_notebook_node(book)
    with open(MAIN_TEX, 'x') as fout:
        fout.write(body)
    print("created:", MAIN_TEX)


def init():
    create_main()
    latex_exporter = LatexExporter()
    # copy `style_ipython.tplx` in `nbconvert.exporters` module to current directory,
    # and modify it so that it does not contain macro definition
    tmpl_path = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(exporters.__file__),
        latex_exporter.default_template_path)
    src = os.path.join(tmpl_path, 'style_ipython.tplx')
    target = CUSTOM_TEMPLATE
    with open(src) as fsrc:
        with open(target, 'w') as ftarget:
            for line in fsrc:
                # replace the line so than it does not contain macro definition
                if line == "((*- extends 'base.tplx' -*))\n":
                    line = "((*- extends 'document_contents.tplx' -*))\n"
                ftarget.write(line)
    print("created:", CUSTOM_TEMPLATE)


def group_cells(note):
    # scan the cell source for tag with regexp `^#latex:(.*)`
    # if sames tags are found group it to same list
    pattern = re.compile(r'^#latex:(.*?)$(\n?)', re.M)
    group = defaultdict(list)
    for num, cell in enumerate(note.cells):
        m = pattern.search(cell.source)
        if m:
            tag = m.group(1).strip()
            # remove the line which contains tag
            cell.source = cell.source[:m.start(0)] + cell.source[m.end(0):]
            group[tag].append(cell)
        else:
            print("tag not found in cell number {}. ignore".format(num + 1))
    return group


def doit():
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        note = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)
    group = group_cells(note)
    latex_exporter = LatexExporter()
    # use the template which does not contain LaTex macro definition
    latex_exporter.template_file = CUSTOM_TEMPLATE
    try:
        os.mkdir(OUTPUT_FILES_DIR)
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    for (tag, g) in group.items():
        book = nbformat.v4.new_notebook()
        book.cells.extend(g)
        # unique_key will be prefix of image
        (body, resources) = latex_exporter.from_notebook_node(
            book,
            resources={
                'output_files_dir': OUTPUT_FILES_DIR,
                'unique_key': tag
            })
        ofile = tag + '.tex'
        with open(ofile, 'w') as fout:
            fout.write(body)
            print("created:", ofile)
        # the image data which is embedded as base64 in notebook
        # will be decoded and returned in `resources`, so write it to file
        for filename, data in resources.get('outputs', {}).items():
            with open(filename, 'wb') as fres:
                fres.write(data)
                print("created:", filename)


if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print("USAGE: this_script [init|yourfile.ipynb]")
elif sys.argv[1] == "init":
    init()
else:
    doit()
```

Comment: This is amazing and solves my problem perfectly! I tested it and it works great. Do you think you could add some comments into the code so I can understand what you're doing? You should make a VS Code plugin that does this.

Comment: Also, a small problem came up where my plots are giving an error. The latex file generated from the tag is looking for an output.png, but the jupyter notebook didn't make one, and neither did main.py. Thanks

Comment: @AdamB I wrote the idea behind the script, and added the comment. I will try to includethe image later on.

Comment: @AdamB I modified the code so that it writes image in jupyther notebook to `./images` directory.

Comment: You’re a hero.  Thanks again for the help. This is a perfect solution. I’m writing and editing at least 5 times faster now.

Comment: Oops, maybe this will cause problem when using multiple cell which has image, so wait for a moment.

Comment: Done. now it should correctly output images to `./images` directory which `tag` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter does not allow exporting specific cells from a notebook -- it only allows you to export the entire notebook.  To get as close to your ideal scenario as possible, you need a modular Jupyter set-up:

1. Split your single Jupyter notebook into smaller notebooks.
2. Each notebook can then be exported to LaTeX via File > Download as > LaTeX (.tex)
3. In LaTeX, you can then import the generated .tex file via

   \input{filname.tex}

If you want to import the smaller notebooks into cells of your main notebook, you can do this via (see magic command [run](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run))

```
%run my_other_notebook.ipynb #or %run 'my notebook with spaces.ipynb'
```

You can also insert python files via (see magic command [load](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-load))

```
%load python_file.py
```

which loads the Python file and allows you to execute it in your main notebook.

You can also have small .py snippets, load them in your small Jupyter notebook, and then run that small notebook in your larger one.

Your use of VS Code is fine, tho, Jupyter in the browser may be faster for you to edit.

([reference for all magic commands](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html))

Comment: This looks very promising, and will definitely help out my workflow. However there are 2 issues that don't completely solve the problem. 1) Say in subnotebook1 I declare x, but then want subnotebook2 to use x's value. How can I do that? If I reference x in subnotebook2 I get a compile error. 2) In my main notebook, I can't see the input from the sub notebooks, only the output. This isn't a huge deal.

Comment: I didn't realize you were trying this in Jupyter python code and not in the notebook web browser. In that case, @ymonad 's answer is more appropriate for your needs

Answer (score 1):

I would use [bookdown](https://bookdown.org) to have both test and source code in the same document (split over several files for convenience). This package originates in the R world, but is also usable together with other languages. Here a very simple example:

````
---
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Setup data

First we define some varialbes with data.

```{python data}
bob = ['Bob Smith', 42, 30000, 'software']
sue = ['Sue Jones', 45, 40000, 'music']
```

# Output data

then we output some of the data.

```{python output}
bob[0], sue[2]
```

# Reference code block

Finally lets repeate the code block without evaluating it.

```{python, ref.label="output", eval = FALSE}
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: This seems like it requires writing in markdown, which then gets converted to latex. Is that correct?

Comment: @AdamB Yes, source language is markdown. Since pandoc is used for the conversion to LaTeX, you can also add LaTeX commands to the source file and they will be handled transparently. That mostly needed for mathematical content needed.